# Plotting all the axes of Accelerometer in MATLAB using XBee+Arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino, xbee

I am trying to plot the real time graph of all the axes of the accelerometer wirelessly by XBee through MATLAB.
I have achieved the following until now:

- On the transmitter side, I have an Arduino connected with an Xbee shield. I am using a Series 2 Xbees for this purpose.
- I have an ADXL335 breakout board accelerometer hooked in to the analog pins Arduino+Shield combo and also the XBee (Co-Ordinator API) on the shield.
- On the receiver side, I have an XBee  (Router AT) connected to a computer which will record the output and plot it in MATLAB.

I also want to mention that I am using the Arduino library for MATLAB for the Arduino code.

Now, when I wire up the Arduino (i.e. I don't use the Xbee) then I get a perfect output of all the axis of the accelerometer.
But when I hook in the Xbee and try to communicate with the arduino I get nothing. E.g. when use the Xbee the command to plot the graph is:

```
a = arduino(COM X);
```

where `X` is the COM port where the Arduino is connected.

How should I change the command when I connect my Xbee? (Recalling again that my Arduino and accelerometer are not connected to the computer but my receiver side Xbee is.)

Here is my MATLAB code:

```
a.pinMode(15,'input'); 
a.pinMode(16,'input'); 
a.pinMode(17,'input'); 
a.pinMode(18,'output'); 
a.pinMode(19,'output'); 
a.digitalWrite(18,0); 
a.digitalWrite(19,1); 
xval = zeros(); 
yval = zeros();
zval = zeros();

xval(1) = a.analogRead(3); 
yval(1) = a.analogRead(2); 
zval(1) = a.analogRead(2);

pause(.001); 

for i = 2:1000

    xval(i) = a.analogRead(3);
    yval(i) = a.analogRead(2);
    zval(i) = a.analogRead(2);


    xmod = (xval-496)/300;
    ymod = (yval-511)/300;
    zmod = (zval-508)/300;

    subplot( 3,1,1)
    plot(xmod, 'r');
    axis([1 1000 -0.5 0.5]);
    title( 'x' );

    subplot( 3,1,2)
    plot(ymod, 'r');
    axis([1 1000 -0.5 0.5]);
    title( 'y' );

    subplot( 3,1,3)
    plot(zmod, 'r');
    axis([1 1000 -0.5 0.5]);
    title( 'z' );

    pause(0.001);

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your setup correctly, it sounds like the problem is that you're using API firmware on the XBee connected to your Arduino.  If you're looking to use XBee modules as a serial cable replacement (i.e., data arrives on serial port of XBee A, and is sent out on serial port of XBee B), then you should use "AT mode" firmware on both, and configure the DH/DL registers with the address of the paired node (with a shortcut of using zeros for DH/DL to indicate the coordinator as the destination node).

The API firmware requires a "smart host" that sends and parses "frames" of data that include header bytes and a checksum footer.

[Digi's XBee Examples Site](http://examples.digi.com) has some nice tutorials on getting XBee modules paired to each other for transparent serial communications.